# How to draw a labeled block diagram showing the relationshop between various router modes?

Tags: networking

How do you draw a labeled block diagram showing the relationshop between various router modes? Can anyone show an example so I can have an idea on what to do.

Thanks!

hear are routes i get after typing show ip route in hyperterminal

C 170.27.0.0116 is directly connected, serial 0/2/0

D 170.26.0.0116 [ 90/20514560 via 170.27.0.1 00:52:15 serial 0/2/0

C 170.28.0.0116 is directly connected . FastEthernet 0/0

Comment: Define "router modes" please.

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more detail as well.

Comment: well im using hyperterminal in a lab session as college and we have to enter commands. we start off entering privileged mode and typing configure terminal from the changing passwords, rip router etc

Comment: ive got three routes after i had type show ip route so i need plz let me know

Comment: then can some show me how to do the diagram

Comment: Just a month or two ago, people that posted homework questions would get blasted here. Did that change? I think this definitely belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Nah, this is a serverfault type question, but not one that's appropriate because it's kinda vague and doesn't really have an answer that would be interesting to anyone else.

Comment: Seriously, homework questions? Close this question...

Comment: @chris, appropriate or not for SF, homework has always been slammed as non-sysadmin related.

Comment: @MarkM: Asking us to do your homework for you is what is not tolerated. Asking me to show you - in this case - HOW to draw the diagram and what tools to use to do so is COMPLETELY different from "Here is a question out of my book, can you draw the diagram for me?" I see no reason to at least try to help him/her out. Also information on how to draw up network diagrams IS useful to people, new and interesting ways to do documentation is always a plus.

"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm still not quite sure what you are looking for, but are you looking for something similar to the below diagram? If so let me know and I can expand on an explaination, or let me know what is missing from this and I'll do my best to get you an example that would be helpful.

[Best guess Image http://www.brokenhaze.com/sf_images/demo.png](http://www.brokenhaze.com/sf_images/demo.png)

Ok, so since this seems to be what you are looking to accomplish - I'll go into a little more detail as to what it says (Note as I said in a comment to the question I won't do the work for your but i'll explain it so that you can do it yourself)

First the basic pieces of the diagram. The grey boxes with arrows in them represent the routers, the lines connecting the routers to other pieces are some sort of physical medium - Ethernet, Serial, whatever. The Line with a bunch of little lines represents an Ethernet network which can have just about anything - clients, servers, embedded devices and the like attached to it.

I've used [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation to describe the networks.

Now lets label the routers in the following way:

ROUTER1 - The router with the 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.2.1/30 and 192.168.2.5/30 IPs
ROUTER2 - The router with the 192.168.2.2/30 and 192.168.3.1/24 IPs
ROUTER3 - The router with the 192.168.2.6/30 and 192.168.4.1/24 IPs

And now I'll match them up to what you would see from the example you gave me of your `sh ip route`

This is your output:

```
C 170.27.0.0116 is directly connected, serial 0/2/0
D 170.26.0.0116 [ 90/20514560 via 170.27.0.1 00:52:15 serial 0/2/0
C 170.28.0.0116 is directly connected . FastEthernet 0/0
```

A `sh ip route` on ROUTER2 in my example would produce something similar:

```
C 192.168.2.0 is directly connected, serial 0/2/0
D 192.168.1.0 [ 90/20514560 via 192.168.2.1 00:52:15 serial 0/2/0
D 192.168.4.0 [ 90/20514560 via 192.168.2.1 00:52:15 serial 0/2/0
C 192.168.3.0 is directly connected . FastEthernet 0/0
```

What this is telling me is that ROUTER2 knows the following:

1. It knows about the 192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.2.1/30 networks because it has a direct physical connection to them. Meaning it has an interface assigned to an ip on that network that is in an up/up state.
2. It knows about the 192.168.1.0/24 network because of a RIP (off the top of my head i think D is the symbol for RIP) announcement to it from ROUTER1
3. It knows about the 192.168.4.0/24 network because of a RIP announcement to it from ROUTER1 which would have gotten it's announcement from ROUTER3

So in a very brief summary, this diagram shows you how all the routers are connected and additionally what networks are behind them. You could also put another label on each of the interfaces showing which networks you announce to the other routers via RIP, OSPF, BGP, RIP2, etc.

I hope that helps you out and let me know if you need any more clarification on any of what is going on here.

Comment: i think something like that ive added my ip routes to the question plz take a look

Comment: @zypher: What tool did you use to make this diagram?

Comment: @chris: I used Dia http://live.gnome.org/Dia - I actually prefer to use Visio when I have to publish my diagrams - but Dia works great for quick n dirty internal diagrams

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consider using tools like Dia for such a task. Or if you want to pay for it, Microsoft Visio can do that for you (more or less).